# Prestashop 1.6 header location in module

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop

Hi I write my first module and I want add redirect to login page: `index.php?controller=authentication`

I add function with: `header("Location: index.php?controller=authentication");`

and also tried do this with this:
`Tools::redirect('authentication.php');`

Every time is error like:

> This web page has a redirect loop
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Any tips?

Comment: Hello, are you trying to redirect from your `ModuleFrontController` ?

Comment: Could you show us some more code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks problem is solved !

@deniskoronets you have right about that :)

On other forum somebody give me thise code:

`if((strpos($url,'login')!==false) || (strpos($url,'authentication')!==false))
    $page='loginpage';
    else
    $page='otherpage';
    if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $page != 'loginpage'){ 
    Tools::redirect('authentication');
    }`

It was very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This web-browser error is shown coz this redirect executes repeatly many times. I think, that your module code is executing also on authorization page, so you try to redirect from auth page to auth page. And code executes again and again...

Comment: I know there is a loop but I dont know why it doesn't stop. This is doesnt matter from what page was redirect.

Comment: It doesnt stop coz possible on your authentication page this module is also executed, so it repeatly try to redirect user on auth page.